# Updating a room when a booking is made: Hotel Booking System, Java, MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, mysql-workbench

im doing a hotel booking system in java and mysql.  My booking page has input details of a client, check-In and check-Out.  Til now, inserting client details, booking details, payments details is going alright but i'm having trouble updating room/s booked by a particular client.

Here's my java code:

```
String dml4 = "select * from room where roomType=? and statusAvailable='Yes'";
                            PreparedStatement ps4 = con.prepareStatement(dml4);
                            ps4.setString(1, cbfirst.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            ResultSet rs = ps4.executeQuery();

                            if (!rs.next() ) {    
                                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No available rooms with roomType specified", "WARNING!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                } 
                            else{
                                //setting room in room table to be occupied
                                String dml5 = "update room set statusAvailable='No' where roomType=?";
                                PreparedStatement ps5 = con.prepareStatement(dml5);
                                ps5.setString(1, cbfirst.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                ps5.executeUpdate();

                            }
```

The problem is that as `roomType='?'`, all the rooms with the particular type (for ex, 'single') is being set to occupied.

How do I get only one room of that particular type to be booked?

```
//inserting into guest table
                            String dml = "Insert into guest (fname,lname, dateOfBirth, gender, phone) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(dml, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                            ps.setString(1, fname.getText()); 
                            ps.setString(2, lname.getText());
                            ps.setString(3, ((JFormattedTextField)dob.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                            ps.setString(4, cbGender.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            ps.setString(5, formaPhone.getText());
                            ps.executeUpdate();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Guest Added Successfully");

                            ResultSet keyOfGuest = ps.getGeneratedKeys();    
                            keyOfGuest.next();  
                            int keyGuest = keyOfGuest.getInt(1);
                            String keyGuest2 = String.valueOf(keyGuest);




                            //inserting into booking table
                            String dml2 = "insert into booking(guestID, checkIn, checkOut, totalPaymentDueAmt) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                            PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(dml2, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                            ps2.setString(1, keyGuest2);
                            ps2.setString(2, ((JFormattedTextField)checkin.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                            ps2.setString(3, ((JFormattedTextField)checkout.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                            ps2.setString(4, tfTotal.getText());
                            ps2.executeUpdate();

                            //inserting into payment table
                            ResultSet keyOfBook = ps2.getGeneratedKeys();    
                            keyOfBook.next();  
                            int keyBook = keyOfBook.getInt(1);
                            String keyBook2 = String.valueOf(keyBook);
                            String dml3 = "insert into payment(bookingID, guestID, paymentMethod, curPaymentAmt, additionalPayment) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
                            PreparedStatement ps3 = con.prepareStatement(dml3);
                            ps3.setString(1, keyBook2);
                            ps3.setString(2, keyGuest2);
                            ps3.setString(3, cbpay.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            ps3.setString(4, tfTotal.getText());
                            ps3.setString(5, null);
                            ps3.executeUpdate();


                            //String dml4 = "update room set statusAvailable='No' where roomType="+cbfirst.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            String dml4 = "select * from room where roomType=? and statusAvailable='Yes'";
                            PreparedStatement ps4 = con.prepareStatement(dml4);
                            ps4.setString(1, cbfirst.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            ResultSet rs = ps4.executeQuery();

                            if (!rs.next() ) {    
                                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No available rooms with roomType specified", "WARNING!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                } 
                            else{
                                //setting room in room table to be occupied
                                String dml5 = "update room set statusAvailable='No' where roomType=? limit 1";
                                PreparedStatement ps5 = con.prepareStatement(dml5);
                                ps5.setString(1, cbfirst.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                ps5.executeUpdate();

                            }
```

Edit: Here is my full code which a JButton has its actions performed.

Comment: Add `limit 1` to your `update` statement. Note that `limit` is supported for `update` here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: If you want to be more specific, you should be assigning id's to the rooms and use that to update the status: "update room set statusAvailable='No' where roomId='numerical'";, this kind of makes more sense so if you want to book a specific room you can do it.

Comment: Yes I do have roomID in my room table, but the user don't select the roomID when booking a room, he selects the roomType...i will try the limit 1 as @Seth Difley said and let you guys know if it worked.

Comment: @Daimonz The roomID should all be handled by the backend programming in java, it is extremely simple. When they select the room type they want you pick the first one available in the list from the DB and use the roomID to update;

Comment: You need to use some unique identifier for each room.. If you use ' limit ' or 'top' keywords with update.. SQL will update the first matching record it finds. To keep a track of which room is occupied or unoccupied pls use unique identifier. It's better if you normalize the database before actual coding.

Comment: @user2494817 the booking is handled by a receptionist.  You mean he should know which roomTypes have their corresponding roomIDs so he can input the roomID when a client requests a 'single', 'double', etc roomTypes?

Comment: @AmeyaKulkarni i have my tables already normalised...the room table is like follows:
room(roomID{PK}, roomType, roomPricePerDay, statusAvailable)

Comment: @Daimonz Take a look at Ameya comment as well, but my thinking is if this list is displayed as a front end interface and you are using lists/objects correctly when you select a room you want to use, it should automatically handle the roomID assignment, or if this is a query based system (recept. searches for a room and it just chooses, the backend code should still handle getting the roomID and updating that way)

Comment: That's good.. So while updating and making the room as occupied along with roomType you need to allocate a room number to the customer and then make only that record as occupied in room table. If while allocating the room if receptionist is giving the roomID as input then you can run the query update update room set statusAvailable='No' where roomType=? And roomID =? This will update only that decide which has the particular roomID.

Comment: @AmeyaKulkarni thanks, i think i got an idea...when the receptionist selects roomType='single' in the booking form, i will put a JCombobox next to it where it will populate the roomIDs of all 'single' rooms whose statusAvailable='Yes'.  Then he only need to select which roomID he wants and the update query will take in the 'roomID' in the WHERE clause as well...thanks

Comment: @SethDifley it works as a quick and dirty solution :P, thanks

Comment: Cool.. It's my pleasure.. Enjoy coding :)

Comment: SQL scripts in java code is a bad style. Try ORM, it'll keep your program less dependent from database you use.